# Problemas al comparar dos variables en php

Tags: php, sql-server, html-tabla

Tengo dos consultas sql server en php y las quiero comparar.

Las tengo de la siguiente manera:

- `$variable1` tiene N cantidad de datos.
- `$variable2` tiene N cantidad de datos.

Ambos variables guardan consultas *SQL Server* de tablas diferentes pero tiene en común el numero de alumno, lo que `$variable1` contiene el total de alumnos y `$variable2` contiene solo algunos... lo quiero mostrar los que son iguales en ambos variables... tengo el siguiente código pero no funciona

```
if($variable1 == $variable2){
$con++;
$variable1;
$variable2;
}else {
     if(($variable1 == $variable2) == null){
     $con++;
     $variable1;
     $variable2;
}
}
```

la variable1 contiene lo siguiente

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

y la variable 2 contiene lo siguiente

```
2
4
7
9
```

lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente

```
1
2         2
3
4         4
5
6
7         7
8
9         9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es comprobar si los elementos de un array se encuentran en otro array (que los datos vengan de una base de datos es lo de menos).

El siguiente código creo que hace lo que quieres.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

$variable1 = array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$variable2 = array(2,4,7,9);

foreach($variable1 as $comp)
{
    if (in_array($comp,$variable2))
        echo "$comp $comp\n";
    else
        echo "$comp\n";
}
```

Échale un ojo a la función [in_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php).